# How To Use "Direct Input" Instead of Keyboard Events In ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, input, keyboard

As you may know in "real" games you need to check if a key is pressed at this time. Right now I'm using events and I remember if last event was a key-up or key-down to know if a button is held down.

**BUT** I'm experiencing some lags (not network) in the game when several buttons are held down. New key pushes are recognized a little bit too late. From DirectInput in DirectX and from LWJGL I know how nice and smooth input for games can work.

---

a) So I ask: **Is there a way to check keys directly in ActionScript 3 ?** I don't think any other extra package would be useful since it would just do what I do right now.

b) If no. Why wouldn't Adobe add direct input feature to Flash since it is used for games to a high percentage ?!?

Comment: You can use keycodes to check lots of different keys. Full list available here: http://www.dakmm.com/?p=272. Although I am not really sure what the problem is you're running into.. you could post your code?

Comment: Maybe you can experient with a `while not key-up` condition in your `key-down Eventlistener`. Keep the action going til `key-up` has been registered.

Comment: @adaam & RST I have all that already. I would like to have a better way to check keys. OS is generating key events after checking hardware state of the key and so does Flash probably using DirectX or whatever. I have to get key states back from events and I want to avoid that.